Парсинг таблицы (общие, различающиеся и пустые данные)
Представим у нас есть таблица в файле .csv
(данные взял тестовые, для удобства и человекочитаемости)



ID
234522
524321
234956
234983
293853




фамилия
Иванов
Тарасова
Петров
Кузнецова
Пушкин


пол
мужской
женский
мужской
женский
мужской


год рождения
1965
1999
1984
1979
2001


должность
инженер
инженер
инженер
инженер
инженер


количество детей
2
1

3



телефон
7485

3310
6500



офис
центральный
центральный
центральный
центральный
центральный


почта
ivanov@post.ru
tarasova@post.ru
Petrov@post.ru





Нужно обработать эти данные:
1 разделить изменяемые и неизменяемые данные:
Неизменяемые данные:



ключ
значение




должность
инженер


офис
центральный



изменяемые данные:



ID
234522
524321
234956
234983
293853




фамилия
Иванов
Тарасова
Петров
Кузнецова
Пушкин


пол
мужской
женский
мужской
женский
мужской


год рождения
1965
1999
1984
1979
2001


количество детей
2
1

3



телефон
7485

3310
6500



почта
ivanov@post.ru
tarasova@post.ru
Petrov@post.ru





2 Разделить пустые и не пустые данные:
пустые данные (строки, в которые есть пустые данные, кроме столбцов, в которых пустые данные отсутствуют)



ID
524321
234956
234983
293853




количество детей
1

3



телефон

3310
6500



почта
tarasova@post.ru
Petrov@post.ru





Непустые данные (только строки):



ID
234522
524321
234956
234983
293853




фамилия
Иванов
Тарасова
Петров
Кузнецова
Пушкин


пол
мужской
женский
мужской
женский
мужской


год рождения
1965
1999
1984
1979
2001


должность
инженер
инженер
инженер
инженер
инженер


офис
центральный
центральный
центральный
центральный
центральный



Хочу их разделить используя pandas, помогите с решением, пожалуйста

Это, вообще-то, простые задачи.
unmutable_data = ["должность", "офис"]
print(df.loc[df["ID"].isin(unmutable_data)])
print(df.loc[~df["ID"].isin(unmutable_data)])
print(df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)])
print(df.loc[~df.isnull().any(axis=1)])

          ID       234522       524321       234956       234983       293853
3  должность      инженер      инженер      инженер      инженер      инженер
6       офис  центральный  центральный  центральный  центральный  центральный

                 ID          234522            524321          234956     234983   293853
0           фамилия          Иванов          Тарасова          Петров  Кузнецова   Пушкин
1               пол         мужской           женский         мужской    женский  мужской
2      год рождения            1965              1999            1984       1979     2001
4  количество детей               2                 1             NaN          3      NaN
5           телефон            7485               NaN            3310       6500      NaN
7             почта  ivanov@post.ru  tarasova@post.ru  Petrov@post.ru        NaN      NaN

                 ID          234522            524321          234956 234983 293853
4  количество детей               2                 1             NaN      3    NaN
5           телефон            7485               NaN            3310   6500    NaN
7             почта  ivanov@post.ru  tarasova@post.ru  Petrov@post.ru    NaN    NaN

             ID       234522       524321       234956       234983       293853
0       фамилия       Иванов     Тарасова       Петров    Кузнецова       Пушкин
1           пол      мужской      женский      мужской      женский      мужской
2  год рождения         1965         1999         1984         1979         2001
3     должность      инженер      инженер      инженер      инженер      инженер
6          офис  центральный  центральный  центральный  центральный  центральный

если unmutable_data нужно вычислить на основании полученных данных, то можно либо так:
unmutable_data = df[df.iloc[:, 2:].eq(df.iloc[:,2], axis=0).all(1)]["ID"]

либо так:
unmutable_data = df.loc[df.iloc[:,2:].nunique(axis=1)==1, "ID"]

UPDATE
Если датафрейм имеет в качестве индекса колонку "ID", то код будет выглядеть так:
unmutable_data = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(df.iloc[:,1], axis=0).all(1)].index
# либо
# unmutable_data = df.loc[df.iloc[:,1:].nunique(axis=1)==1].index
# здесь выводим только ключ и значение
print(df.iloc[:, :1].loc[df.index.isin(unmutable_data)])
print(df.loc[~df.index.isin(unmutable_data)])
print(df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)])
print(df.loc[~df.isnull().any(axis=1)])


Наверное, unmutable_data тоже нужно автоматом определить, а не вручную задать )

unmutable_data = ["должность", "офис"]
нужны общие решения, мы же не знаем какие данные не меняются, таблицы гигантские, я сделал их тестовый вариант

@polsok Ну возьмите уникальные значения по строке или столбцу, что у вас там и посчитайте кол-во. Если 1, то вот это константа значит там. Потом с этой маской можно сделать выборку.

@CrazyElf как-то мне это было не очевидно из вопроса, но, тем не менее, ответ я обновил.

@polsok я обновил ответ.

@strawdog
unmutable_data = df.loc[df.iloc[:,2:].nunique(axis=1)==1, "ID"] выдает все ключи,
а
unmutable_data = df[df.iloc[:, 2:].eq(df.iloc[:,2], axis=0).all(1)]["ID"] при print(unmutable_data.index) выдает такое ответ: Index(["должность", "офис"], dtype='object', name=0)

@polsok в моем ответе датафрейм имеет колонку с цифровым индексом. Если у вас индексом является "ID", то разумеется нужно корректировать код. я обновил ответ.
